# Launching VFP / LWC to outside users who are not in Salesforce

Tags: apex, community, salesforce1-app, force.com-sites, appexchange

Requirement here is to have a feedback form open on a browser. `Plan is to send an email with link to launch the form with few survey questions. So the option that I know is to set up a Salesforce Site & expose an LWC containing questions.`

When we send an email containing link to VFP/LWC will just open in a browser but it will still ask for user login.
Wanted to check with this community that, is there any alternates where I can just send a link and on submit, I will have to store the response in a custom object completely avoiding the log in process ?
I did see Guest Access to the Support API option, but it is more associated to creating a Case in service cloud.

**Bottom line is, what's the best way to expose a component so that any user outside of the org can access it**.

*In most of the case, the receivers are stored as Contact in Salesforce.*

looking for suggestions here. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have couple of options:-

1. You can use a site which just have VF page or LWC form, You can share the site link for survey, this does not requires any login
2. You can use [LWR Unauthenticated Sites for Experience Cloud](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.exp_cloud_lwr.meta/exp_cloud_lwr/intro.htm)
3. You can have a webpage where you can expose your inbound rest api which will insert the record.